# User Input Validation with Conditional Statements in Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need help with validating user input and some conditional statement stuff within this function.So I have a modal with 3 inputs and 3 corresponding submit buttons in my html.

I want this function below to take the
user input number when the submit button is clicked, so that it can be validated and further manipulated.

An issue im running into is, when the input is left empty and the submit is clicked, the function continues and executes
the final piece of code that is only supposed to be done when the first 2 conditions of the function have been met.

I have
made the condition for when the input value is blank or null or NaN but the code for that condition does not execute.

```js
const submitBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("pledge-submit-btn");
for (let i = 0; i < submitBtns.length; i++) {
  submitBtns[i].addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    let currentAmount = parseInt(document.querySelector("#second-main-section-backers").innerHTML.replace(/\$|,/g, ''));
    const target = 100000;
    const pledgedAmountInput = parseInt(e.target.previousElementSibling.firstElementChild.value);
    const minimumPledgeRequired = e.target.previousElementSibling.firstElementChild.min;
    if (pledgedAmountInput == '' || pledgedAmountInput == null || pledgedAmountInput == isNaN) {
      alert("A pledge is required");
      return;
    } else if (pledgedAmountInput < minimumPledgeRequired) {
      alert("A minimum pledge of $" + minimumPledgeRequired + " is required.");
      return;
    } else {
      let newAmount = pledgedAmountInput + currentAmount;
      document.querySelector("#second-main-section-backers").innerHTML = "$" + formatter.format(newAmount);
      localStorage.setItem("amountRaised", newAmount)
      let newProgressBarWidth = Math.round((newAmount / target) * 100);
      progressBar.style.width = newProgressBarWidth + "%";
      localStorage.setItem('progressBarWidth', newProgressBarWidth);
      let currentBackers = parseInt(document.querySelector("#total-backers").innerHTML.replace(/,/g, ''));
      currentBackers++;
      document.querySelector("#total-backers").innerHTML = formatter.format(currentBackers);
      localStorage.setItem('TotalBackers', currentBackers);
      let stockLeft = e.target.parentElement;
      stockLeftAmount = parseInt(stockLeft.parentElement.previousElementSibling.firstElementChild.innerHTML);
      stockLeftElement = stockLeft.parentElement.previousElementSibling.firstElementChild
      stockLeftAmount--;
      stockLeftElement.innerHTML = stockLeftAmount;
      pledgeSuccessModal.style.display = 'flex';
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="pledge-selection" id="pledge-selection-black">

  <p class="pledge-selection-heading">Enter your pledge</p>

  <div class="input-btn-field">

    <div class="input-icon">
      <input class="pledge-amount-input error" placeholder="75" min="75" id="pledge-amount-input-black" type="text">
      <i>$</i>
    </div>

    <button href="#" class="pledge-submit-btn">Continue</button>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. It has console errors

Comment: You do not have  second-main-section-backers